# bash shell script transmission variable value space processing, how to space data it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, beanshell

**bash shell script transmission variable value space processing, how to space data it**

```
**#FileList. list.txt Delivery list belowt**
  $1          $2           $3
xxxx1.com_1 Hello_2 Hello_3 - Hello
xxxx2.com_1 Hello_2 Hello_3 - Hello


get_list() {
now_list=${1} #Pass list

while read -r line; do #Circular reading
now_list_url=$(echo "${line}"|awk -F ' ' '{print $1}') #url variable1
now_list_keyword=$(echo "${line}"|awk -F ' ' '{print $2}') #keyword variable2
now_list_title=$(echo "${line}"|awk -F ' ' '{print $3}') #title variable3

#print
echo "url：${now_list_url}"
result：xxxx1.com_1

echo "keyword：${now_list_keyword}"
result：Hello_2

echo "title：${now_list_title}"

result：Hello_3    #Due to the empty grid of the transmission variable 3
result：Hello_3 - Hello    #And want to be correct
done < "${now_list}"
}

#Run
get_list list.txt`
```

Transfer variable 3 due to space errors：Hello_3
I want correct transmission variables 3 due to space and finally the correct result：Hello_3 - Hello

#And here is because the transmission variable is incomplete,The result I finally need is the value of the value of the output complete variable 3 in the value of the complete variable3 = "Hello_3 - hello"
Because of work needs, a lot of list processing, I will save the variable value in the text
How should I deal with it

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you should let `read` split the fields, instead of using `awk`:

```
while read -r now_list_url now_list_keyword now_list_title; do

    echo "url：${now_list_url}"
    # result: xxxx1.com_1

    echo "keyword：${now_list_keyword}"
    # result: Hello_2

    echo "title：${now_list_title}"
    # result: Hello_3 - Hello

done < "${now_list}"
```

Since three variables were given to `read`, it'll try to split the line into three fields. When there are more than three space-separated things in the line, all the extra gets put in the last variable. See [BashFAQ #1: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more information.

Comment: Hello, after I found that after using this method, echo "$ {now_list_title}" will change the number, as long as all the values after output this variable will be abnormal.

Comment: set -x 
      echo "${now_list_url}||${_site_dns_com_cnt}"
      echo "${now_list_url}||${now_list_keyword}||${now_list_title}||Test character"
————————————————————————————————————
result

||Test character'om||keyword||goodkey - good2site
||Test characterrd||goodkey - good2site

Comment: @study That sounds like the input file is in DOS/Windows format, and has a carriage return at the end of each line (in addition to the newline that `read` expects). You can tell `read` to discard it with `while IFS=$IFS$'\r' read -r now_list_url now_list_keyword now_list_title; do`. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) for more information and options.

Comment: In the current method, use "IFS = $ ifs $ '\ r'".
get_text now_list_title
But I use the GET_TEXT method to use the Now_list_title variable value. After the get_text method, the now_list_tital variable value will still change the line.

Comment: No, I added "IFS = $ iFS $ '\ r'" and I still change it. I will send you the result to see

Comment: echo "${now_list_url}||${now_list_keyword}||${now_list_title}||ce1"
————————————————————————————
result
||ce1.com||godkeyword||godkeyword - godtext

Comment: jnpxw.com godkeyword godkeyword - godtext 
_____
These are three corresponding variable values

Comment: That's definitely a carriage return getting in there. Is this running in bash, or some other shell? Other shells may not understand the `$'\r'`. Also, make sure the capitalization and spacing are correct; they're wrong in what you just said. Use back-quotes to quote code and literal strings in your comments so they won't be weirdly formatted.

Comment: I feel file coding problem